# Why is this python code giving me a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(x)
```

The `double_list` call on the last line is giving me a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You should always post the *full* error.

Comment: You will be getting a `NameError` because you have not define `x`. Hope you wanted to pass `n` as argument

Comment: @dlmeetei: It's totally a dupe. The NameError is the *next* error the questioner would get, after they fix the current error.

Comment: Agreed, My oversight.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3, the print syntax has been changed in order to bring more consistency with the rest of the Python syntax, which uses the brackets notation to call a function.

You must always do `print(....)` with the brackets, hence the `SyntaxError`.

```
print(double_list(x))
```

However, I do not see the rest of your code, so maybe you also have another iterable called `x`.
Otherwise you must also replace `x` by `n`, to avoid getting a `NameError` this time.

Answer (score -2):

What is `x` in `double_list(x)`, and why do you think it has that value?

Did you mean `double_list(n)`?

Comment: That would cause a `NameError`, not `SyntaxError`.